# Big O and Omega Properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I am trying to think of a case where this is not true:

$f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $f(n) \neq \Omega(g(n))$, does $f(n) = o(g(n))$?

I suspect that it has to do with the varying $c$ and $n_{0}$ constants but am not completely sure.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of $\Omega$?  According to one definition,  $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ is the negation of $f(n)=o(g(n))$, and according to another it means $g(n)=O(f(n))$.  (If it means the latter there are counterexamples.)

Comment: $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ means $f(n) \geq c \cdot g(n)$ for all $n \geq n_{0}$. Still unsure..

Answer (score 2):

You can read the relations this way.

- $f \in O(g)$ means that $f$ eventually stays below some multiple of $g$.
- $f \in \Omega(g)$ means that $f$ eventually stays above some multiple of $g$.
- $f \in o(g)$ means that $f$ eventually stays below *any* multiple of $g$.

So if $f\not\in \Omega(g)$, $f$ must dip below any particular multiple of $g$ infinitely often.  But that doesn't mean it *stays* below that multiple.  And knowing that $f\in O(g)$ doesn't help much; that just means $f$ doesn't dominate $g$.  So a counterexample to your question, for instance, is obtained by taking $g(n)=1$ everywhere, $f(n)=1$ for even $n$, and $f(n)=1/n$ for odd $n$.  Then $f$ is $O(g)$ (it's $\le g$), it's not $\Omega(g)$ (it dips below any constant infinitely often), and it's not $o(g)$ (it doesn't stay below $g/2$, say).

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(n) = n+(-1)^nn$ and $g(n) = n$.